# Pin tool for Android 5

Tags: android, intel-pin

Does the [Intel's Pin tool](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/256671/pindroid-tutorial-01_1.pdf) support Android version 5 or 6  ? [This](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/256671/pindroid-tutorial-01_1.pdf) document explains 
how to install PIN tool for Android. I tried to install Pin tool on android version 5 and 6.

In both version, when I try to execute the pin tool,  I am getting following error:

```
Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_phone_x86/generic_x86:6.0/MASTER/2524533:userdebug/test-keys'
  3 Revision: '0'
  4 ABI: 'x86'
  5 pid: 2310, tid: 2310, name: pinbin  >>> /data/local/tmp/ia32/bin/pinbin <<<
  6 signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
  7     eax 00000000  ebx 00000906  ecx 00000906  edx 00000006
  8     esi b6f16c50  edi 00000002
  9     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
 10     eip b6ce9606  ebp 00000906  esp bf8823f4  flags 00000206
```